# Spectrum of the Hill Operator $L(y)= -y''+ v(x) y $

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Consider the eigenvalue equation for the Hill operator 
$$L(y)= -y''+ v(x) y = \lambda y, \quad x\in \mathbb{R},$$
where $v(x)$ is any potential and $\lambda$ is the spectral parameter. If $v(x) \equiv 0$, the spectrum of $L$ subject to periodic boundary conditions (*bc*): $y(0)=y(\pi)$, $ y'(0)=y'(\pi)$ and anti-periodic *bc*: $ y(0)=-y(\pi)$, $ y'(0)=-y'(\pi)$ coincides with the spectrum subject to Dirichlet *bc*: $y(0)=y(\pi)=0$; that is $\lambda_n=n^2$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $n$ is even or $n$ is odd, respectively.

My concern is about the inverse problem: If we know that the spectrum with respect to above boundary conditions coincides as above, what can we say about the potential $v(x)$? Does it have to be identically zero?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.
the potential $ v(x) $ can be recovered from the spectral data..

let us suppose we know the energies $ E_{n} $ or the Spectral staircase $ N(E) $

then $$ v^{-1}(x)= 2\sqrt{\pi} \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}N(x) $$

if the boundary condition $ y(0)=0 $ is included

and $$ v^{-1}(x)= \sqrt{\pi} \frac{d^{1/2}}{dx^{1/2}}N(x)$$

if we asume the potential is even $ v(x)=v-x) $

Comment: Of course, we can recover the potential but what's your argument? How do you get it? Besides, I don't understand the terminology.

Comment: it is semiclassical WKB method :) to recover the potential